# How to remove time from datetime in SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, node.js

Here is my query:

```
select date(datetime) as dates,
        user_id,
        sum(CASE When status='completed' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as completed,
        sum(CASE When status='incompleted' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as incompleted,
        sum(CASE When status!='' Then 1 Else 0 End ) as total 
from routine_streak 
where user_id ='"+user_id+"' 
and datetime  between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"' 
group by user_id,date(datetime)
```

It will give output like this:

```
"datetime": "2019-01-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

However I want it like this:

```
"datetime": "2019-01-30"
```

Comment: psql (Team sql)

Comment: That query wont give you anything, it has a syntax error in it

Comment: The Query you posted in your question is not valid in multiple ways (the colon after `date(datetime)` mustn't be there and the bracket at the end should be removed)

Comment: could you please tell me in this query how we can use join to fetch user name from user_id

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Answer (score 0):

use query like this given below

```
<?php 
var str = "select DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%y-%m-%d') as dates,from routine_streak where user_id='183' group by user_id)"; 
?>
```

Comment: not working it show internal server error in my api response

Comment: nidhi, provided syntax is of mysql please provide us which database are you using?

Comment: i m using psql  query with node js

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```
 SELECT
      date_format(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dates,
      user_id,
      sum(CASE WHEN status = 'completed'
        THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END) AS completed,
      sum(CASE WHEN status = 'incompleted'
        THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)  AS incompleted,
      sum(CASE WHEN status != ''
        THEN 1
          ELSE 0 END)  AS total
    FROM routine_streak
    WHERE user_id = '"+user_id+"'
          AND datetime BETWEEN '"+start+"' AND '"+end+"'
    GROUP BY user_id, dates
```

Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Use the cast function to get the date part only

```
cast(datetime as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for **SQL SERVER**

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
```

Output will be as expected.